# Corda Ledger size questions

Tags: corda

I hava multiple questions about the disk size which Corda needs over time and could not find any information online.

1. How much disk space does a Corda transaction need?
2. How musch disk space does Corda need over the course of 10 years with 4.5 million transactions per month on average (without attachment etc.)

Comment: Oh great. Another project that defers all its support to SO.

Answer (score 1):

The size of a transaction is not fixed. It will depend on the states, contracts, attachments and other components used.

We do not have any rough guides currently, but we will likely be doing some tests shortly in the run-up to the release of Corda's enterprise version. This will give an idea of the storage requirements of running a node.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the CordApp example of an ultra simple IOU transaction to measure this. A single IOU transaction contains the identity of two counterparties and one notary and a singe double value (requiring 8 bytes).

Looking at the database I see that the serialised transaction requires 11 kB.

I am asking for alternative ways for serialisation in: [Corda: Large serialized transaction size: Are there alternatives to current serialization design?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51709928/corda-large-serialized-transaction-size-are-there-alternatives-to-current-seri)

Answer (score 0):

As was said the answer is it depends on the transaction size. The average bitcoin transaction runs about 560 bytes, giving around 2000 transactions per 1 meg block. Ethereum runs an average of about 2K per transaction so it can store 500 per 1 meg block and from best numbers I can get hyperledger runs about 5k per transaction to around 205 per block. Assuming CORDA will be somewhere in this spectrum, and assuming you will use the less is more axiom (store as little as possible in the blockchain block, defer all else to sideDB or offchain storage) then lets chose something easy to calculate with, let's say CORDA has a 1k per transaction average. That is 1000 trans/block. With the 1k size multiply TPS*seconds of processing in a day*actual processing days per year to get your number. In your case (4,500,000*1024*12*10)/(1024^3) should give you gig. (seems to be about 515 gigabytes at a 1k transaction size)

Comment: That means your transaction rate is only 1.73 TPS, are your sure that is enough?